# textcat function is case sensitive, is it a bug?

Tags: r

I faced an issue using language detection function `textcat()`.

```
library(textcat)

textcat('ogłoszenie')
# [1] "polish"

textcat('OGŁOSZENIE')
# [1] "slovenian-iso8859_2"
```

'Ogłoszenie' is a polish word, but when written in capital letters is detected as  slovenian. Does anyone know how to avoid the issue?

Now I use `tolower()` on text.

Comment: Keep it lowercase, what is the problem?

Answer (score 1):

By default it is using `textcat::TC_char_profiles` profile where `tolower` is set to `FALSE`. We can create a new profile and change it to `TRUE`, see below:

```
library(textcat)

# create a new profile with tolower option TRUE
myProfile <- textcat::TC_char_profiles
attributes(myProfile)$options$tolower <- TRUE

textcat('OGŁOSZENIE', p = myProfile)
# [1] "polish"
```

Or we could just do, as your suggested workaround:

```
textcat(tolower('OGŁOSZENIE'))
# [1] "polish"
```

Comment: That helps! Thank You :)

Comment: @KamilaWyrwas if this was useful please consider accepting, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) and [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) for more info.